# Matrix multiplication with multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, join, matrix

I have a quick question regarding Threads.

I have the task to compute the multiplication of two matrices recursively by dividing the matrices always into smaller matrices until a certain Threshold dimension is reached (then a sequential multiplication is executed)

This should be done by several threads that do this recursive Division and then put the results they get together to a bigger matrix...

That's why certain Threads have to wait for each other, especially the parent Thread has to wait for all its children. (I hope the recursive aspect get clear here)

My question would be the following
First of all if a parent Thread instantiates and start a certain set of Threads

```
Thread [] threads = {t1, t2, t3, t4};

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t4.start();
```

and if I wanted to let this parent Thread wait until all of these are finished would this do the Job:

```
 for (Thread t :
            threads)   {
        t.join();
    }
```

In other words is this for loop "atomic" or could it be that if we started all of these threads and we do the first iteration in this for each block that the second iteration of this for loop is just executed if t has terminated. (since join lets the parent thread wait until the Thread you call the join function is terminated)

Moreover, I wanted to ask, regarding my initially explained task, how you could implement that certain threads are "mutually waiting" for each other, since join() is pretty one sided, I guess. What I mean is: if t1 is faster than t2, t1 waits and the other way around.

Thank you so much in advance
Jonny

Comment: Re, "how you could implement that certain threads are "mutually waiting" for each other...?" When two or more threads are mutually waiting for each other, we call that a [_deadlock_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock), and we usually consider it to be a Bad Thing.

Answer (score 0):

> if I wanted to let this parent Thread wait until all of these are finished would this do the Job...?

Yes. `t.join()` returns when thread `t` has terminated, and not before. Your loop joins each of the threads in the `threads` array, so therefore, the loop will complete almost immediately after the last of the threads have terminated, and not before.

`t.join()` waits for thread `t` to terminate if `t` still is running, but it returns immediately if `t` already has terminated.

---

> is this for loop "atomic"...?

The word, "atomic" is pretty much meaningless in this case.

Threads communicate with each other by modifying shared variables. We call a sequence of operations on one or more shared variables "atomic" if, when one thread performs the atomic sequence, it is impossible for any other threads to see the variables in a half-way-done state. "Atomic" means that other threads looking at the variable(s) can only ever see them as they were before the atomic sequence started, or after the atomic sequence was complete.

The reason why "atomic" has no meaning in your example is, your `for` loop does not access any shared variables.